# Unable to SMS using AT commands for arduino uno

Tags: arduino, arduino-uno, gsm

```
#include <SoftwareSerial.h>

SoftwareSerial mySerial(0, 1);

void setup()

{

  mySerial.begin(9600);   // Setting the baud rate of GSM Module 

  Serial.begin(9600);    // Setting the baud rate of Serial Monitor (Arduino)

  delay(100);

}

void loop()

{

  if (Serial.available()>0)

      SendMessage();

 if (mySerial.available()>0)

   Serial.write(mySerial.read());

}

 void SendMessage()


{

  mySerial.println("AT+CMGF=1");    //Sets the GSM Module in Text Mode

  delay(1000);  // Delay of 1000 milli seconds or 1 second

  mySerial.println("AT+CMGS=\"+1876xxxxxxx\"\r"); // Replace x with mobile number

  delay(1000);

  mySerial.println("I am SMS from GSM Module");// The SMS text you want to send

  delay(100);

  mySerial.println((char)26);// ASCII code of CTRL+Z

  delay(1000);

}
```

I am trying to send a sms using SIM 800 RPI GSM ADD-on v2.3 module through the arduino platform however everything I try fails. Please assist and explain where i am going wrong. Thank you. My code is above. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You are missing a carriage return in `"AT+CMGF=1"`.

Change `"AT+CMGF=1"` to `"AT+CMGF=1\r"`

Although having delays between command works and suffices the purpose but is not recommended.
It is preferable to catch and analyze the messages returned by the SIM800 especially in case of error has occurred.